# Not able to deploy Cloud end point backend module

Tags: java, android, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I am working on an android project which uses data from Google data store. For this I have JSP & Servlet based admin module which will be used to upload data. To read data from Android client application I have cloud entry points.

Thus, I have created a module comprising of JSP, servlets, and cloud entry points. This is working fine with local dev server. Able to access data through android app.

Now, trying to deploy the module to Google App Engine. But getting following error:

> SEVERE: Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an
>   error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate
>   with it.

What could be missing here?

Let me know if anymore information needed regarding this issue.

Please help me in this regard.

**Full trace:**

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /root/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg --application=rotary-bidar-01 --version=1 --oauth2 --oauth2_client_secret=***** --oauth2_client_id=***** --oauth2_refresh_token=***** update /mnt/4CF2AADEF2AACC10/Projects/Rotary_Bidar/AndroidApplication/RotaryBidar/server/build/exploded-app
Reading application configuration data...
Jan 16, 2016 11:28:59 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /mnt/4CF2AADEF2AACC10/Projects/Rotary_Bidar/AndroidApplication/RotaryBidar/server/build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jan 16, 2016 11:28:59 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /mnt/4CF2AADEF2AACC10/Projects/Rotary_Bidar/AndroidApplication/RotaryBidar/server/build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/web.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: '/tmp/appcfg5838290850638628913.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /tmp/1452967141068-0/org/apache/jsp/admin_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Jan 16, 2016 11:29:10 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /tmp/appcfg5838290850638628913.tmp/WEB-INF/web.xml
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
28% Cloning 13 static files.
31% Cloning 50 application files.
40% Uploading 2 files.
52% Uploaded 1 files.
61% Uploaded 2 files.
68% Initializing precompilation...
73% Sending batch containing 2 file(s) totaling 1KB.
90% Deploying new version.
95% Will check again in 1 seconds.
98% Will check again in 2 seconds.
99% Will check again in 4 seconds.
99% Will check again in 8 seconds.
99% Will check again in 16 seconds.
99% Will check again in 32 seconds.
99% Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.
Jan 16, 2016 11:30:32 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload checkEndpointsServingStatusResult
99% See the deployment troubleshooting documentation for more information: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/test_deploy#troubleshooting_a_deployment_failure
SEVERE: Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.
99% Ignoring Endpoints failure and proceeding with update.
99% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
99% Uploading index definitions.

Update for module default completed successfully.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

Comment: Tried the same backend module with maven build and upload. It worked without any issues.

Comment: Perhaps a transient issue with endpoints? has it been happening consistently?

Comment: I am having this issue since a few days, but I don't think anything changed on my side. The last thing I want is to convert my project to maven. Is there any other solution?